# ShopifySharp does not return all metafields

Tags: c#, shopify

I am trying to set metafields on my products. I have some special ones defined in shopify. But when i run the code it returns only three. Im not sure how to return the others.

```
            var service = new MetaFieldService(strShop, strKey);
            var metafields = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                return await service.ListAsync();
            }).Result;
```

The three that returned are none of those that i have created, they seem to be a part of some app or maybe the system itself.

Any ideas?

I tried to use other methods but it seems the MetaFieldService is the only way of accessing this information. Looked through documentation and google but did not find a solution for this problem.

Comment: You need to be specific about your Metafields. Shopify has made many of them and you are not specific. Are you interested in private ones your API created? Public ones anyone created? You know you can query with namespace and keys? How do you even know the ones that exist, and that your basic query is not working for?

Comment: Sorry for the vauge question. Yes, i have created the Metafields myself under "product" space. I have 5 different ones and they are all created as single text lines and with predefined values. I can see them under the product card in shopify so they are defined and active. Im not sure how to list Meta´s under a specific namespace, cant find a variant of the ListAsync-function that do that.